# Certutil -revoke

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

i am trying to use certutil to manage my CA. Is there a possible way to user Certutil -revoke "RequestID=?"

I only see it for the SerialNumber of the certificate wich is not really handsome.

Envy

Comment: What is the problem to retrieve serial number from RequestID?

Comment: if i want to revoke with the serialnumber i have to type the whole number in my command thats 20 characters. the request id are a maximum of 6 characters.

Comment: Then there are no other ways to revoke by request ID. You must provide serial number.

Comment: To resolve the RequiestID for a certificate by it's serial number use `& certutil -view -restrict "SerialNumber=1600002a4c376fd805b39162d7000400002a4c" -out RequestId`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `certutil` as follows:

```perl
 & certutil -revoke 1600002a4c376fd805b39162d7000400002a4c "6"
```

Where `6` is the reason code (`Certificate Hold`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own PowerShell function to achieve that. You will need two `CertUtil.exe` calls for that:

1. Use `CertUtil.exe` to get the serial number of the certificate with your given `$RequestId`:

   ```
   CertUtil.exe -view -silent -restrict "RequestId=$RequestId,Disposition=20" -out 'SerialNumber'
   ```

   Parse the serial number from the output into `$SerialNumber`.
2. Use `CertUtil.exe` to revoke the certificate:

   ```
   CertUtil.exe -revoke $SerialNumber 0
   ```

---

`Disposition=20` will filter issued certificates only.

`-revoke` uses different revoke reasons. You can look them up [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil#-revoke).